# Rigged model distorting

Tags: rigging

I rigged a fairly low poly model and when bending the joints this happens. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>  is not connecting anything.

I am fairly new to Blender.

[image]

Comment: Watch these two tutorials on character topology 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5G9ziFbJJmM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5Jksu5Z8AA Also it seems like not all of your faces are connected. Try merging verticies by distance.

Comment: Thank you for useful links. There was a problem that occured when imported from obj to rhino 6 to obj to blender which caused subsurf mod to not function properly.